why all my aws-node Pods in CrashLoopBackOff State in Kubernetes Cluster
I'm currently facing an issue with my Kubernetes cluster where all the aws-node pods in the kube-system namespace are in a CrashLoopBackOff state. Here are the details of my setup:
Kubernetes Version: v1.23.17 (EKS)
Cloud Provider: AWS
CNI Plugin: AWS VPC CNI

Observations:
The aws-node pods are crashing repeatedly.
Other pods in the cluster are experiencing network connectivity issues, as they rely on the aws-node pods for networking.
I have checked the logs of the aws-node pods, but I’m unable to identify the specific cause of the crashes.

Ensure the API server endpoint access is both Private and Public to ensure the pods are reachable from the control Plane
